# No alternative for table layout?

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists, tablelayout

I do understand. Tables must be used only for tabular data, not for layout in any case. 
I used to write code with lots of tables, but several years ago i've found ways to replace them with more appropriate structures in every situation. **Except one.**

```
<ul>
<li>We're up</li>
<li>all night</li>
<li>to get</li>
<li>lucky</li>
<li class="last_one"><input type="search" placeholder="I'm search"></li>
</ul>
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/4enMp/4/

I'm trying to make a menu here. My requirements:

1. The menu must fill all the page horizontally **[menu width: 100%]**
2. All the menu cells (except for the last one) should have random widths, depending on the widths of their contents **[width of menu item = width of item's content].** It means it should not be hardcoded.
3. The last menu item (with search input) should stretch to fill all the remaining space. **[last menu item fills all the space left].**
4. The whole thing **must support IE7+.** It's silly. I know. But it is something I can do nothing about. Thankfully I don't have to bother with IE6.

As I've illustrated in JS Fiddle, it's pretty easy to do that with tables (though I don't claim it's 100% right, it's consistent across browsers).

I have not managed to meet these 4 requirements with unordered lists (see Fiddle above). I would greatly appreciate any thoughts of how to reach it with **HTML and CSS only.**

Thanks a lot for your help!

Edit: here's my desired menu design:
[image: Desired menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need to have your input field in the same element as your menu. They serve pretty different functions. I would probably approach this by breaking the input field out of the unordered list, and just floating it right. It uses a little more HTML but totally works.

Comment: I don't. If it's possible to do it with two separate floated elements, it suits me. But the menu should look monolithic. Here's my real menu: ![Menu](http://vitapunkt.ru/123.jpg). As you can see, I can't apply 1 background for 2 elements: only <li> should have backgrounds because of specific active (pressed) menu item design

Comment: Indeed. You would need to wrap both your unordered list and your search field with a div, and apply the background to the div instead of the unordered list.

Comment: Ok. But in this case how can I style the active button like it's shown on the picture (it looks like it is pressed, so there's no gradient background)?

Comment: By putting your "active" background on the list item? It will be overlapping your gradient.

Comment: Well. As you have noticed, the background of document is a pattern. Doing like you said is acceptable in this case, because users are unlikely to see the difference between body and "active" backgrounds... if the background was not so simple, this approach would fail. So, thats why I check your answer as best. Thanks a lot for your help! But I would be delighted to see the universal solution that doesn't depend on background ...

Comment: Thanks! I think, in general, different techniques must be used for different designs. A universal solution might be optimistic. Just do what makes sense for what you're trying to achieve. These days, backgrounds such as yours are less common. Simple, flat design is very easy to build.

Answer (score 3):

Your current problem seems to be with the the last `li` being `width: 100%`, which will make the li be the size of the ul, thus being pushed off the "screen".

An easy fix would be to make that `li` have a `position:absolute;`.

[Live example](http://jsfiddle.net/4enMp/6/)

Edit: I'd mostly agree with Kate though. You should probably make the search separate from the `ul` and just float it right.

Comment: Sam, the fiddle on my comment was to fit what Kate suggested. I cant comment on others' answers as I dont have the reputation for it yet. You would need to set the background to the wrapping `<div>`, and then set the background to the `<li>` to set it as the active link

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/4enMp/5/

```
ul {
    display: table;
}
li {
    display:table-cell;
    line-height:30px;
}
```

Comment: Technically yes, thanks. +1 for that. My fault that i didn't mention that I unfortunately have to support IE7+. And IE7 does not support display:table-cell. sorry. have updated the question

Comment: c'mon, I would not post this just to get the answer to "make ul behave like a table with display:table". Sorry once again. Do you think it is impossible to do that other way??

Comment: IE7 is almost as crippled as IE6.  You can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear.  Either use a table or use JS.